# Google Photos API - Is there a way to get direct, permanent, link to images?

Tags: php, image, url, google-photos-api

Quite simple question about these new APIs: I already created a system fetching album images, but the **baseUrl** expires after a while.

Is there a system to get a non-expiring URL? Until today I was using Picasa APIs (*now closed*), giving me a permanent URL.

I need a direct access to the picture.

Comment: I'm wondering about the same.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way around the expiration of the `baseUrl`.

You need to save the `mediaItem.id` as it is a permanent, stable ID used to identify the object.

Then you can fetch the `GET https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems/{mediaItemId}` when you need the baseUrl.

You can also save the baseUrl and on a 403 error get a fresh one with the `mediaItem.id`

My understanding is that the calls to:

> `GET https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems/{mediaItemId}`

and

> `GET https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:batchGet`

do no count against the daily quota.

Answer (score 0):

My background is in Nodejs but I thought I'd still share my findings as it'll give you an idea on how to solve your issue.

It's not possible to get permanent URLs for Google Photos because they expire after 60 minutes.
If you're planning to use OAuth 2.0 which asks for user credentials before displaying images every time, please see this code sample that does exactly that (in Nodejs):
https://github.com/googlesamples/google-photos

Alternatively, there's a simpler way to share images - which is to store the images on the Google Drive instead of Google Photos and then creating a 'service account' on the Google Developer Console to link the drive to this account. This method provides permanent links to the images.

Please see this very helpful article on this implementation:
https://medium.com/@abhimanyuPathania/google-drive-service-accounts-and-nodejs-a038b8ec482f

Hope this helps.

Comment: My system already has a Google Drive integration. I was also using picasa (Google+) APIs though, that's why I need exclusively Google Photos now.. but there seems to be no options..!